# Deconstructing an array in increments of two

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array like so:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a"]
```

How can I deconstruct it in into individual variables in increments of two? So that `let one = [1, 2]`, `let two = [3, 4]`, etc? I know that you can deconstruct an array using individual variables like so:

```
let one, two, three;
[one, two, three] = arr
```

But doing it in increments of two, is that possible?

Comment: In a **single** destructuring statement? No, you'd need an intermediate step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an array and assign the value to the explicit target.

An automatic assignment is on the left hand side not possible by using a spread syntax with arrays with a length of two.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a"],
    one = [], two = [], three = [];

[one[0], one[1], two[0], two[1], three[0], three[1]] = array;

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way you could do this is via [ES6 generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a']

function* batch (arr, n=2) {
  let index = 0
  while (index < arr.length) {
    yield arr.slice(index, index + n)
    index += n
  }
}

let [first, second, third] = batch(arr)

console.log(first)
console.log(second)
console.log(third)
```

Or even more generic approach as kindly suggested by [@Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a']

function* batch (iterable, length=2) {
  let array = [];
  for (const value of iterable) {
    if (array.push(value) === length) {
      yield array;
      array = [];
    }
  }
  if (array.length) yield array;
}

let [first, second, third] = batch(arr);

console.log(first)
console.log(second)
console.log(third)
```

And finally a [curried](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-es6-curry-functions-with-practical-examples-6ba2ced003b1) version:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a']

const batch = length => function* (iterable) {
  let array = [];
  for (const value of iterable) {
    if (array.push(value) === length) {
      yield array;
      array = [];
    }
  }
  if (array.length) yield array;
}

let [first, second, third] = batch(2)(arr);

console.log(first)
console.log(second)
console.log(third)
```

Answer (score 3):

`.flatMap()` is a combination of `.map()` and `.flat()` it allows the callback to skip returning values, return a value, and return multiple values which is made possible by returning arrays which get flattened in the final step. This demo has a callback which is a ternary that returns 2 values in an array every other iteration while it returns an empty array on alternating iterations. The result is an array of arrays which is then destructured.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a"];

let newArr = arr.flatMap((node, index, array) => index % 2 !== 0 ? [
  [array[index - 1], node]
] : []);

let [A, B, C] = newArr;

console.log(A);
console.log(B);
console.log(C);
```

Comment: You could define a reusable batch function implemented with `flatMap()` like this: `const batch = length => array => array.flatMap((_, i) => i % length === 0 ? [array.slice(i, i + length)] : []);` Then `const [A, B, C] = batch(2)(arr);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've seen a pattern like this: `const batch = length => array =>`  and I tried to recall where I've seen it before, but to no avail. Can you please enlighten me?.

Comment: Look in the other answer I helped. `f = a => b => ...` is called currying, and it allows functions to be more reusable via partial application, e.g. `g = f(1); g(2)`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks @PatrickRoberts. I think I've sen a similar pattern done with on-event properties . At the time I thought it was some kind of chaining made possible by bind or something but maybe it is a group of curried event handlers/?...not sure, I'll have to research curried functions, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following steps:

- Use `reduce()` on the array and set accumulator to `[]`
- During each iteration check the current index is divisible by the given number(`2`).
- If it does then add an empty array to the end to accumulator.
- Add the current element to the last subarray of accumulator each time.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a"];
let [first,second,third] = arr.reduce((ac,a,i) => {
  if(i % 2 === 0){
     ac.push([]);
  } 
  ac[ac.length - 1].push(a);
   return ac;
},[])

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
console.log(third);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another [curried](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400) version using a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), but this one uses [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to yield the values:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a'];

const getChunk = (len) => function * (arr)
{
    arr = arr.slice(0);

    while (arr.length >= len)
        yield arr.splice(0, len);

    yield arr;
}

let [one, two, three, four] = getChunk(2)(arr);
console.log("Chunks of size 2 =>", JSON.stringify([one, two, three, four]));

[one, two, three, four] = getChunk(3)(arr);
console.log("Chunks of size 3 =>", JSON.stringify([one, two, three, four]));

[one, two, three, four] = getChunk(1)(arr);
console.log("Chunks of size 1 =>", JSON.stringify([one, two, three, four]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score -2):

> is that possible?

Most anything is possible with coding.

```js
let group = (arr, count) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
    let last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    if (last.length < count)
      last.push(v);
    else
      acc.push([v]);
    return acc;
  }, [[]]);

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a"]
console.log(group(arr, 2));
console.log(group(arr, 3));
console.log(group(arr, 5));
```